# How can I create a custom link Magento 1.9.3.x admin side menu?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-ce

I'm trying to create a custom section with custom links on Magento 1.9 admin side menu, but it doesn't redirect me to my controller action

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/local/Your/Module/controllers/Adminhtml/MassActionController.php

```
<?php

class Your_Module_Adminhtml_MassActionController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {

    /**
     * @return bool
     * give acl permissions
     */
    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public function yourfunction() {
    }
}
```

> app/etc/config.xml

add this outside global tags.

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Your_Module before="Mage_Adminhtml">Your_Module_Adminhtml</Your_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

Comment: I already have a router registered, but my link is set as `admin/system_config/edit/section/my_section_name`

Comment: Im not getting what your issue is . Please post your code and more info.

Answer (score 0):

I want to change the *Module custom link* href to my custom page

system.xml:

Section tab

`<tabs>
        <paymentmoduleconfig translate="label" module="paymentmodule">
            <label>My section</label>
            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        </paymentmoduleconfig>
    </tabs>`

Menu item

`<module_custom_page translate="label" module="paymentmodule">
            <label>Module custom link</label>
</module_custom_page>`

adminhtml.xml:

`<config>
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <system>
                        <children>
                            <config>
                                <children>
                                    <module_custom_page translate="title" module="paymentmodule">
                                        <title>Module custom page</title>
                                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                                    </module_custom_page>
                                </children>
                            </config>
                        </children>
                    </system>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>`